# change combination reference code to regular reference code in admin prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have little difficulties, I have admin order with Prestashop version 1.7.6, in the admin order as Prestashop rules that the reference code for the products with the combination is coming through product options but I want to show instead of that reference what is the regular reference code of the product like its coming for the product who have not product options.

I know where is the combination reference code into the admin end if I will change it will work like regular but there are 900+ products so I just want to make it correct with code.

reference with the combination:

[image]

Regular product reference:

[image]

into the admin where I want to change

[image]

And here is the code of the admin order:

file path : `localhost/pre7/admin231nuevxm/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_product_line.tpl`

```
<a href="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminProducts', true, ['id_product' => $product['product_id']|intval, 'updateproduct' => '1'])|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
            <span class="productName">{$product['product_name']}</span><br />
            {if $product.product_reference}{l s='Reference number:' d='Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'} {$product.product_reference}<br />{/if}
            {if $product.product_supplier_reference}{l s='Supplier reference:' d='Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'} {$product.product_supplier_reference}{/if}
        </a>
```

`{$product.product_reference}` is the variable. I want to make it a regular reference. unfortunately, it's same for regular and combination

I have tried regular reference code `{$product->reference}`  into the product page and its working fine there but not working into the admin order.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this myself finally define an array in correct way  {$product['reference']}

Thanks